# zsh: permission denied: /Users/jailbreak/Desktop/project/n.py

Tags: macos, zsh, permission-denied

I tried to open n.py through terminal on mac os big sur, although zsh shows that permission denied

Answer (score -1):

change permission of the file.

```
chmod +x n.py
```

Then try to execute the file again.

```
python n.py
```